# ChildNode of custom type is returning Nil on Swift Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift-playground, skscene

I have a class with name (Player.swift). then in my (Scene.swift) class, I declared my object like this.

```
var player: Player?
```

then in my initializeGame function, I am doing like this

```
private func initializeGame() {

    player = childNode(withName: "Player") as? Player!;
    //print NIL
    print(player?.name);
    // initializePlayer()is declared in Player.swift
    player?.initializePlayer();
    print(player?.name);
    //Print NIL
    scoreLabel = childNode(withName: "ScoreLabel") as? SKLabelNode!;
    scoreLabel?.text = "0";
}
```

I made my ios project in Xcode,  and its working fine,  then i create a Playground project and import all the xcode files in this project, My playground is running properly except the player is not functioning properly. The problem is in associating the Player Node with custom class in .sks file. The name of my Xcode project is "Game play" so  I  write Game Play in module  and Player in custom class, and using that same sks file in Playground causing problem, the name of my playground project is  "MyPlayground", so the module name should be same as project name, so i edit the module field to Myplayground, still not working. So guide me how to change that properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-Open your (.sks) file

2-Select the Player Node.

3-Select Show custom class inspector.

4-Write "MyPlayground_Sources" instead of just MyPlayground.

Answer (score 0):

The method `childNode(withName:)` returns an **existing** child node that has been added to the node hierarchy. If no node is found with that name, then it returns `nil`.

Do you have code that adds a node with the name "Player"? Is it a node of type `Player`? Is it being called?

Comment: check the edit please. The problem is in associating the Player Node with custom class in .sks file.

Comment: Swift (and Objective C for that matter) is case-sensitive, so make sure the module name matches exactly the import you are using in your .swift file.

Comment: I haven't played around with .sks files before, but let me see if I can put together a quick demo to replicate your issue.

Comment: https://github.com/niqbal/playgroundtest
this is the link to my github repo, you can download the project from there
myplayground.playground file.